# Reverse for 'shop.product_detail' not found. 'shop.product_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name. DJANGO 2.1

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-2.1, django-errors

I cant see were i made a mistake, I tried almost everthing. Even checked stackoverflow but I cant find mistake... Please can you detect were I went wrong?

This is Printscreen of an error :

http://prntscr.com/mgnfyz

shop/views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404
from .models import Category, Product


def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_list_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)


    context = {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products
    }
    return render(request, 'shop/list.html', context)

def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_list_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    context = {
        'product': product
    }
    render(request, 'shop/detail.html', context)
```

urls.py in shop app  :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product-list'),
    path('<category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by-category'),
    path('<slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product-detail'),
]
```

base.html in shop app within templates and then shop folder agian :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}On-line Shop{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
{% include 'shop/navbar.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True ,db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

If you need anything else tell me. But i think this is enough to spot an error. Please help, im stuck 2 days with this error and cant solve it.
<3

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake....In my list.html i misspeled wrong url pattern. `({% url 'shopproduct_list' %})`, instead i  just needed to use name of my url like this `{% url 'product-list' %}`
Just in case if u can this error check urls in ur html documents. Maybe you misspelled something .

Cheers